# How to set a combined maxlength of two input fields in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wanting to set a combined maximum length of 64 for two input fields in angular, so if say that for the first field the user enters 40 characters, in the second field the maxlength becomes 24.

So far I have tried to write is like so...

js

```
function newCat() {
  var cat =  {
    id: $scope.id,
    name: $scope.name
  };

  $scope.idMax = 64 - ($scope.name)
  $scope.nameMax = 64 - ($scope.id)

  [irrelevant code]

  return cat
};
```

html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <h3>id</h3>
  <input ng-maxlength="idMax" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="id">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <input ng-maxlength="nameMax" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name">
</div>
```

This hasn't worked though.

Can anyone suggest how it would be possible to fix what i've done, or what would be a better way to go about fixing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some piece of code that may help you.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name=''; $scope.id='';
    var max = 10;
    $scope.update = function()  {
     $scope.remaining = max - ($scope.name.length + $scope.id.length);
     $scope.idMax = max - ($scope.name.length);
    $scope.nameMax = max - ($scope.id.length);
    }
    $scope.update();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h3>id</h3>
  <input maxlength="{{idMax}}" type="text" ng-model="id" ng-change="update()"> Length: {{id.length}}
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <input maxlength="{{nameMax}}" type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="update()"> Length: {{name.length}}
  <p>Remaining: {{remaining}}</p>
</div>
```

Run it and see if its what you were trying to achieve.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45nr9sk3/)